# Scroll TreeView control to top

Tags: c++, c, winapi, treeview

How can I scroll my Tree View control to the top?

For example we have some tree with a lot of elements:

```
Root element
|-- item 1
|-- item 2
|-- .....
|-- item 1567
```

Tree View control can display only 5 node at the same time. As result, when I press Expand button, it expand all items and shows me only the last 5 nodes.

I want so that after expanding it returns view to the first 5 nodes.

I tried to use this macros to return caret back to the root, but they take no effect:

```
TreeView_Select(hTreeView, hRoot, TVGN_CARET);
TreeView_SelectSetFirstVisible(hTreeView, hRoot);
```

Comment: First get the tree control object for your tree view by calling **GetTreeCtrl** and call **GetChildItem()** of tree control on the root item(**GetRootItem()**) to get its first child item, then use **EnsureVisible()** on that child item

Comment: Pure C. Is Win32 api different for C and for C++?
TreeView_EnsureVisible() works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use Windows API (and the macros). You can ensure an item is visible with TreeView_EnsureVisible. If you do not have the root item you can get it with TreeView_GetRoot.

Answer (score 1):

In C# winform, the following code makes it scroll back to top:

```
        ResultTree.ExpandAll();
        ResultTree.Nodes[0].EnsureVisible();
```

Using some Node instead of the whole tree, you scroll back to the node.
Try if there is anything like this in C++.